# Devexpress Vertical Grid not accessible for assertion in Coded UI Test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, devexpress, coded-ui-tests

When I drag the cross hair of assertion to the vertical grid, it can just access the header(left column), but not the data(right column).

How can I assert on the data in Vertical Grid?

Comment: When you use the crosshairs, have you manipulated the highlighted control using the small arrows in the properties window to navigate between siblings? Sometimes I cannot directly highlight an object using the crosshairs and have to navigate that way to get to it. If you really cannot see that object, we've gotten around it by having coded ui call sikuli to do some basic verification. Not ideal, but sometimes the only option for "shy" controls.

Comment: @yonitdm, Yep I tried to explore that properties windows, no luck!

Comment: then while not ideal, if you must assert the contents of that "invisible" section I'd recommend http://www.sikuli.org/ It is scripted in Python and uses image matching for assertions and UI navigation. It is possible to call a sikuli script from within coded UI. Here is a thread with examples: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/232233